# Why does MySQL InnoDB cluster not show MySQL server instances in MySQL shell?

Tags: mysql-innodb-cluster

I followed the [docker innodb cluster](https://github.com/mattlord/Docker-InnoDB-Cluster) manual method to create an InnoDB cluster. Now in the MySQL server instance, by running `select * from performance_schema.replication_group_members`, I can see the group contains three nodes:

[image: mysql select statements gives three nodes in the group]

However, the MySQL shell gives only one node in the cluster:

[image: mysql shell shows 1 node in the cluster]

Why  are they not identical?  I think the replication group is the same thing as an InnoDB cluster in this example.

Comment: well, it has to be manually added into the cluster. by running `dba.getCluster().addInstance()` in mysql shell.

Answer (score 1):

The **unofficial** [docker innodb cluster](https://github.com/mattlord/Docker-InnoDB-Cluster) manual does not use MySQL Shell to set up and configure the MySQL InnoDB cluster.

If you want/need to use the MySQL Shell to manage your InnoDB cluster then you must "adopt" the running Group Replication group. To do so, use the `adoptFromGr` option of `dba.createCluster()`:

```
dba.createCluster("testcluster", {adoptFromGr: true})
```

For more information, please consult the [official userguide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-from-group-replication.html).